# Application can't be moved to SD card

Tags: android

I have put the following in `AndroidManifest.xml` as described in the [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html):

```
<application android:name="MyApp" ... android:installLocation="auto">
    ...
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

but the `Move to SD card` is remaining disabled for my application (other installed applications on my phone can be successfully moved to SD card). What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is it an app or a widget? If I remember correctly, Widgets can not be moved to SD card.

Comment: I hit this same issue when I was working on my application last night.  I had to completely uninstall the application and then re-install it to get the Move to SD Card option to become enabled.  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just tried this. You have the line inside the appliction tag. Agreed it doesn't work.
The article shows it as part of the manifest tag like:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nbt.keypad"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="auto">
```

Then it works for me.

Comment: How could I be so scattered? Damn!